# When Passing message as sweet alert text ,Not Working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, alert, sweetalert, sweetalert2

This is my Code in MVC view:

```
@if(msgs != null) { 
    <script>
    {
        sweetAlert({
          title: "User Registration",
          text: "" + msgs + "",
          type: "success",
          confirmButtonText: "OK",
          allowOutsideClick: "true"
        });
    }
    </script>
}
```

It Does Not execute alert ,But when i replace **text:""+msgs+""** with **text:"Some Message"** it executed Alert Successfully.
I need to Pass Message Dynamically.

Comment: How you're passing the `msgs` string? If never assigned, `msgs` always have either empty value or null.

Comment: No, I Pass Some Message to msgs from controller Via Viewbag.Message.  Previously i assigned as var msgs=viewbag.Message;

Comment: So, you should have `var msgs = '@ViewBag.Message'` somewhere, and put check against null or empty string. Are you already passed string to `@ViewBag.Message` from controller?

Comment: ya, Previously i assigned as var msgs=viewbag.Message..

Comment: msgs is fiilled with correct message that is "Registered Successfully" so only it come inside script but only problem is cant pass to sweetalert text

Comment: This code looks ok, you need to post more relevant code to understand the problem.

Comment: A simple `text: msgs` should be enough, empty strings are unnecessary for concatenation. Check if the console contains any error, because the code seems has no problem.

Comment: @VigneshD Edit your question and add your code there.

Comment: @VigneshD Avoid posting code in comments, edit your question to include them as reference.

Comment: Maybe you can share jsfiddle.net link?

Comment: i have no idea about jsfiddle. what to  do?

Answer (score 0):

try this. you're not quite mixing your server-side and client-side correctly:

```
@if(msgs != null) { 
    <text>
    <script>
    {
        sweetAlert({
          title: "User Registration",
          text: "@msgs",
          type: "success",
          confirmButtonText: "OK",
          allowOutsideClick: "true"
        });
    }
    </script>
    </text>
}
```

where `@msgs` is the string value from `ViewBag`